# SwiftUI Coredata MacOS App extremely slow after a bit of use

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui, lag

I'm writing a SwiftUI app that frequently saves and retrieves data from Coredata. After using my app for a few minutes, or doing something that causes lots of Coredata saves, the app becomes extremely slow and never speeds back up. I don't really even know where to start in troubleshooting this...

This is my PersistenceController:

```
import CoreData

struct PersistenceController {
    static let shared = PersistenceController(inMemory: false)

    let container: NSPersistentContainer

    init(inMemory: Bool = false) {
        container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Cubing_TimerApp")
        let storeURL = try! FileManager
                .default
                .url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
                .appendingPathComponent("Cubing_TimerApp.sqlite")
        let storeDescription = NSPersistentStoreDescription(url: storeURL)
        if inMemory {
            container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first!.url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/dev/null")
        } else {
            container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [storeDescription]
        }
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        
    }
}
```

This is an example of a function that might be saving to Coredata a lot:

```
func deleteSolve(_ solve: Solve) {
    viewContext.delete(solve)
    do {
        try viewContext.save()
    } catch {
        let nsError = error as NSError
        fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
    }
}
```

I have 2 Coredata entities, Instance and Solve. Instance has a one-to-many relationship with solve.

I also have code that allows me to detect when the space key is pressed and released, which I figured might cause some slowness:

```
class KeyDetector: ObservableObject {
    @Published var spaceIsPressed: Bool = false
}

class KeyboardManager {
    static var isInitialized = false
    
    private static let keyDetector = KeyDetector()
    
    static var keyStates: [CGKeyCode: Bool] = [
        .kVK_Space: false,
    ]
    
    static public var initializer: KeyDetector {
        if isInitialized == false {
            pollKeyStates()
            isInitialized = true
        }
        
        return keyDetector
    }
    
    static func dispatchKeyDown(_ key: CGKeyCode)
    {
        if key == .kVK_Space {
            keyDetector.spaceIsPressed = true
        }
    }

    static func dispatchKeyUp(_ key: CGKeyCode) {
        if key == .kVK_Space {
            keyDetector.spaceIsPressed = false
        }
    }
    
    static func pollKeyStates() {
        for (code, wasPressed) in keyStates {
            if code.isPressed {
                if !wasPressed {
                    dispatchKeyDown(code)
                    keyStates[code] = true
                }
            } else if wasPressed {
                dispatchKeyUp(code)
                keyStates[code] = false
            }
        }
        
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(25)) {
            pollKeyStates()
        }
    }
}
```

However, I tried disabling it and it was just about as slow.

Another thing that seems like it is causing some lag is a list of Coredata objects:

```
struct SolveList: View {
    @State var instance: Instance

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(instance.solveArray.reversed()) { solve in
                Text(String(solve.time))
            }
        }
        .id(UUID())
    }
}
```

Ideally it should be able to show hundreds/thousands of items, and it seemed like it was causing some more lag with about 100. However the app is still very slow when there are only a couple.

Unsurprisingly, CPU usage is pretty consistently at about 100%, almost all of which is from the main thread. I included the code which I thought was most relevant to the problem but I'm happy to share any of it in case what I put here isn't enough.

Anyways, any help figuring out what's going on or how to speed it up would be very appreciated, since I'm kind of at a standstill with progress on it now.

Thanks!

Comment: Remove any `.cornerRadius()` and replace with `RoundedRectangle` recently I was able to significantly improve my `List` by just doing that change.

Comment: Maybe this is a good time to learn and start using [Instruments](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/MeasuringPerformance.html)

Comment: @Joakim what instruments would you recommend I learn? I’ve used time profiler a bit but there are some parts of it I don’t understand yet.